# I'm trying to implement a "Read more" link in my projects page (react js) portfolio

Tags: reactjs, toggle, use-state, portfolio

So when the user clicks on "read more" for a particular project, it should expand the description of it. It works but whenever I click on "read more" for one project, it expands the description for all the other projects as well. I only want the description of the particular project that was clicked.

Please find below the code snippet

```
                <PortfolioContainer>
                    <SingleProjectContainer>
                        {projectData.map((singleProject)=>{
                        const {title, description, id} = singleProject;
                        const lessDescription = description.slice(0,100) + "....";
                        return (
                            
                                <div className="cardStyled" key={id}>
                                    
                                    <ProjectName>{title}</ProjectName>
                                    
                                    
                                        {readMore ? <ProjectDescription>{description}</ProjectDescription>: <ProjectDescription>{lessDescription}</ProjectDescription>}
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <span className="test" onClick={functionToggle}>{readMore ? "read less" : "read more"}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                            
                                
                        );
                    })}
                    </SingleProjectContainer>
                    
                </PortfolioContainer>
```

and this is the toggle function

```
const functionToggle = ()=>{
        setReadMore(!readMore);
    }
```

Thank you so much

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes brother, it worked. I upvoted this answer by since my reputation is less than 15 it just recorded the feedback. Thanks

Comment: you can accept the answer (Green tick) if it worked. it's the green tick. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `map` method `readMore` is applied to all looped items.
You need to add another case in your tenary operator in order not only to check that you are in read more mode but that the current title matches the article you need to expand.

```
<span className="test" onClick={() => functionToggle(title)}>{readMore ? "read less" : "read more"}</span>
```

then along with adding a new variable to your state

```
const [ currentFocusedTitle, setCurrentFocusedTitle] = useState(null)

const functionToggle = (title)=>{
        setReadMore(!readMore);
        setCurrentFocusedTitle(title);
    }
```

and then

```
 {readMore && currentFocusedTitle === title ? <ProjectDescription>{description}</ProjectDescription>: <ProjectDescription>{lessDescription}</ProjectDescription>}
```